# Закрытие используемой вкладки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Объясните как сделать так чтобы вкладка которая используется закрывалась.(что то подобное как в браузере) чтобы добавлялся крестик для закрытия ( если это реально сделать)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
def center():
    qr = root.frameGeometry()
    cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
    qr.moveCenter(cp)
    root.move(qr.topLeft())
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
hbox = QHBoxLayout(root)
topleft = QFrame(root)
topleft.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
topleft.resize(10,0)
topright = QFrame(root)
topright.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
splitter1.addWidget(topleft)
splitter1.addWidget(topright)
hbox.addWidget(splitter1)
hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
tab = QTabWidget()
First_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(First_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Основа")  # вкладки
Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame = QFrame()
tab.addTab(Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame, "Дополнительно")
hbox1.addWidget(tab)
topright.setLayout(hbox1)
root.setLayout(hbox)
root.setFixedSize(1366,720)
center()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
menubar = QMenuBar()
closefile = QAction( 'Закрыть', root)
closefile.triggered.connect(lambda : Second_frame_of_the_Right_frame.close())
fileMenu_file = menubar.addMenu('File')
fileMenu_file.addAction(closefile)
hbox.setMenuBar(menubar)
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он у вас закрывается, вы просто этого не видите. Ведь фрейм пустой. Добавьте на него виджет, тогда будет видно.

Comment: @mkkik а разве это не должно работать как по типу полностью закрыть данный фрейм тип останется только вкладка основа?

Comment: А с чего бы? Вы же закрываете фрейм, а не вкладку.

Comment: @mkkik а можете показать как тогда вкладку закрыть а то я что то не понимаю вроде как фрейм и есть так сказать влкадка

Comment: `closefile.triggered.connect(lambda : tab.removeTab(1))` 1 - это номер вкладки (нумерация с нуля).

Comment: @mkkik я так понимаю это работает только по ID по имени так не будет работать?

Comment: Нет. И это не ID, а порядковый номер.

Comment: @mkkik не могли бы вы помочь как сделать так чтобы вкладка на которой сейчас происходит работа закрывалась а не определенная которая прописана?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос или задайте новый, чтобы люди с похожей проблемой смогли найти решение.

Comment: @mkkik отредактировал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, как закрывать активную вкладку по событию, а также как добавить кнопки закрытия для каждой вкладки.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QTabWidget,\
                            QVBoxLayout, QMenuBar, QAction

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.tabwdg = QTabWidget()
        self.tabwdg.setTabsClosable(True) # включение отображения кнопок закрытия
        self.tabwdg.addTab(QWidget(), 'first')
        self.tabwdg.addTab(QWidget(), 'second')

        self.tabwdg.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.closeTab) # связывание сигнала нажатия на "крестик" с обработчиком

        box = QVBoxLayout()
        box.addWidget(self.tabwdg)

        self.setLayout(box)

        bar = QMenuBar(self)
        menu = bar.addMenu('File')

        action = QAction('Close activ tab', self)
        menu.addAction(action)
        action.triggered.connect(self.closeActivTab)

    def closeActivTab(self):
        activ_tab_ind = self.tabwdg.currentIndex()
        self.closeTab(activ_tab_ind)

    def closeTab(self, ind): # метод закрывает вкладку под номером ind
        self.tabwdg.removeTab(ind)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication([''])
    w = Window()
    w.resize(300, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: а можно как нибудь сделать чтобы была кнопка на вкладке что то вроде закрытия ее ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Обновил ответ.